# How to inject using interface in dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, interface, dagger-2, dagger

Considering the following structure:

```
public class WaterWorld implements IWorld {

    ...
    @Inject
    CreationMode creationMode;

    @Override
    public final void init() {
        WorldModule.getComponent().inject(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible for `WaterWorld` to get dependencies if the `Component` has following structure:

```
    void inject(IWorld world);
```

I am getting null this way. However, if I try to do it in the following

```
    void inject(WaterWorld world);
```

then it works. However, I have many classes implementing `IWorld`. I wanted to do it this way: `void inject(IWorld world);` How to do this or is there some other generic solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, Dagger will always inject the class specified in the `inject(Foo foo)` method. It will inject objects in the parent types, but it will *not* inject objects in subclasses.
Dagger uses the type specified to generate code for the injection, but if you don't specify the specific class then Dagger simply doesn't know about it and won't inject its fields.

*Note:* You don't give any specific example, but it looks like you could be very well using constructor injection instead, which has no need for manual injection or inject methods in your component. If you have multiple implementations of the same interface you might even take a look at multi bindings with Dagger.